# Jquery - Set focus to window

Tags: jquery, focus, window

any ideas why this not work?

```
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
    $(window).bind('keyup', function(e) { if (e.keyCode == '27') 
    { 
        $('body').append('focus window <br />');
        $(window).focus(); 
        $(document).focus(); 
    } });

   $('#test').focus();

});
```

**example**
http://jsbin.com/agayen/edit#preview

Comment: use anonymous functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is to remove focus from the text box when you hit escape, so try this (in your event handler):

$(e.target).blur();

In this example focus never leaves from the window so you can't assign it back.

You could test to see if the target is valid for a blur call too - e.g. test if it's an input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you don't need to give the function a name. There you are defining a function, not calling one:

Instead of:

```
$(document).ready(function ubsrt()
{
```

Use:

```
$(function ()
{
```

Comment: no, that is not the problem. I mean that i cant set the focus out of the textarea.